# How to mix multiple images with audio with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

When mixing multiple images with an audio with `ffmpeg`, I read the photos from a folder containing repeated photos equal to the number of frames in the output video.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i LIST_OF_FRAMES -i AUDIO -vsync vfr -strict -2 VIDEO
```

For a single still image, I use the command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i IMAGE -i AUDIO -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage
-preset ultrafast -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest VIDEO
```

I need to mix four images to be shown with 25% intervals throughout the video. I wonder if there is a way to use a command similar to the second one to avoid creating repeated images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text file should have duration directives in it, with the last image entry duplicated.

```
file image1
duration 10
file image2
duration 10
file image3
duration 10
file image4
duration 10
file image4
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -f concat -safe 0 -i LIST_OF_FRAMES -i AUDIO -vf fps=1 VIDEO
```

(You don't need `-strict -2` unless your ffmpeg is from before 2016).